# split string and store only certain part of the split javascript

Tags: javascript

Im not sure if this is possible say I have something like this...

`/account/register#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik56RXhNemRETUVRME9EWkdOMFJHUmtRMk9VUXdNemxFUWpWQk1UaEdNVFpCTURneU0wWXhSZyJ9.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.UBileHlEfQbuQgOPk60EkpTHAxxC_o0-4C4No6sCLbqTwEHljLKcKhA1CQhcMdtcn2a1c1YnV1Ka5AdYxh65iKGOEqMcauhIFKXkeO2E_X_mpv9x26HJzEJVzsg3PKzGKE8iAthzp_wXZf8Xqgnt7XAeKh6rTvpigZ2yjMdykCHu-rZgokaPO1CuYsFSibPf_ewS3zMHVbPGd1M2k-wvWiIV9anudkNLG4H0luEyBkrzNtKaa5x0z-YdNKhlApetcMC2QRbuHFbBGrCaQNTUJ5lnu-pMeT6llnRpLT9oE08elVcuEppXCXFRl-JFkbcWp-ft5BSOeTNkavEwb_jpJg&state=tBo7J0ySFXKMuVkKrdj3FURzoG5Y7Hu6`

is there a way I can split the string at the `=` after `#id_token` and only save the token to a variable and then just discard the rest??

I know I could split at the `=` and put the two halves in an array and then `token = array[1]` Im just wondering if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a *better* way as that's subjective.  If you want to be more specific than using `=` you could use a more explicit regex pattern:

```js
let string = '#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik56RXhNemRETUVRME9EWkdOMFJHUmtRMk9VUXdNemxFUWpWQk1UaEdNVFpCTURneU0wWXhSZyJ9.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.UBileHlEfQbuQgOPk60EkpTHAxxC_o0-4C4No6sCLbqTwEHljLKcKhA1CQhcMdtcn2a1c1YnV1Ka5AdYxh65iKGOEqMcauhIFKXkeO2E_X_mpv9x26HJzEJVzsg3PKzGKE8iAthzp_wXZf8Xqgnt7XAeKh6rTvpigZ2yjMdykCHu-rZgokaPO1CuYsFSibPf_ewS3zMHVbPGd1M2k-wvWiIV9anudkNLG4H0luEyBkrzNtKaa5x0z-YdNKhlApetcMC2QRbuHFbBGrCaQNTUJ5lnu-pMeT6llnRpLT9oE08elVcuEppXCXFRl-JFkbcWp-ft5BSOeTNkavEwb_jpJg&state=tBo7J0ySFXKMuVkKrdj3FURzoG5Y7Hu6'

let token = string.match(/#id_token=(.*)/).pop() 
   
console.log(token)
```

Comment: Be sure the match string exists; otherwise, it'll error.

Comment: Hey another quick question at the end there is `&state=tBo7J0ySFXKMuVkKrdj3FURzoG5Y7Hu6` which I dont want is there a way I can remove that also??

Comment: First, @CertainPerformance's solution of URLSearchParams is a good and valid option for what you may be after.  That said, you could easily customize the regex string above to stop at the next ampersand.  You'd want to change `.*` to `[^&]+` and that way it'll match on anything not an ampersand (and stop at the first ampersand it encounters)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason @CertainPerfomance's solution is not working for me, plus I will have to support IE so this is better for my circumstances

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in `URLSearchParams` instead of messing with string parsing yourself:

```js
const input = '/account/register#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik56RXhNemRETUVRME9EWkdOMFJHUmtRMk9VUXdNemxFUWpWQk1UaEdNVFpCTURneU0wWXhSZyJ9.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.UBileHlEfQbuQgOPk60EkpTHAxxC_o0-4C4No6sCLbqTwEHljLKcKhA1CQhcMdtcn2a1c1YnV1Ka5AdYxh65iKGOEqMcauhIFKXkeO2E_X_mpv9x26HJzEJVzsg3PKzGKE8iAthzp_wXZf8Xqgnt7XAeKh6rTvpigZ2yjMdykCHu-rZgokaPO1CuYsFSibPf_ewS3zMHVbPGd1M2k-wvWiIV9anudkNLG4H0luEyBkrzNtKaa5x0z-YdNKhlApetcMC2QRbuHFbBGrCaQNTUJ5lnu-pMeT6llnRpLT9oE08elVcuEppXCXFRl-JFkbcWp-ft5BSOeTNkavEwb_jpJg&state=tBo7J0ySFXKMuVkKrdj3FURzoG5Y7Hu6';
const params = new URLSearchParams(input);
console.log(params.get('/account/register#id_token'));
```

If you need to support IE, use the [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) too.

Comment: Hey I tried this but I keep getting back null?? please see my updated question with the full url im trying to grab the queryParams from

Comment: @JuvenileSnow See edit: if your query string starts with something different than what you posted the first time, then just substitute in the *actual* start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using String method *substring()*

```
const string = '#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik56RXhNemRETUVRME9EWkdOMFJHUmtRMk9VUXdNemxFUWpWQk1UaEdNVFpCTURneU0wWXhSZyJ9.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.UBileHlEfQbuQgOPk60EkpTHAxxC_o0-4C4No6sCLbqTwEHljLKcKhA1CQhcMdtcn2a1c1YnV1Ka5AdYxh65iKGOEqMcauhIFKXkeO2E_X_mpv9x26HJzEJVzsg3PKzGKE8iAthzp_wXZf8Xqgnt7XAeKh6rTvpigZ2yjMdykCHu-rZgokaPO1CuYsFSibPf_ewS3zMHVbPGd1M2k-wvWiIV9anudkNLG4H0luEyBkrzNtKaa5x0z-YdNKhlApetcMC2QRbuHFbBGrCaQNTUJ5lnu-pMeT6llnRpLT9oE08elVcuEppXCXFRl-JFkbcWp-ft5BSOeTNkavEwb_jpJg&state=tBo7J0ySFXKMuVkKrdj3FURzoG5Y7Hu6';
const token = x.substring('#id_token='.length);
```

Documentation for substring():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring